# Handlebars.js not working with AJAX JSON response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, handlebars.js

I am trying the simple Handlebars.
Initially I have tried with static Javascript array object for handlebars data,it is working fine. 
So I tried with Javascript Array object as JSON String from Java RestURL(to make handlebars data dynamic) and compiling the handlebars. Where I get data from RestURL via AJAX call and even the template is also building from handlebars.The real problem is when the template function is called, It is not generating the response data with template.
Following is HTML Code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Handlebars.js Demo</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/handlebars.js"> </script>
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<table>
<thead>
<th>id</th>
<th>username</th>
<th>password</th>      
</thead>
<tbody>
{{#Users}}
<tr>
<td>{{id}}</td>
<td>{{username}}</td>
<td>{{password}}</td>          
</tr>
{{/Users}}
</tbody>
</table>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$.ajax({
url:"http://localhost:8082/Backbone/rest/test/test1",
method:'get',
success:function (results) 
{
var source   = $("#some-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$("#content").html(template(result));
}
})   
});
</script>
</html>
```

The java Rest Code:

```
@Path("/test")
public class Common
{
@GET
@Path("/test1")
public Response getMsg() 
{
Users user=new Users(1,"harish","ram");
String output=toJson(user);
return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
public String toJson(Object object)
{
Gson gson=new Gson();
String str=gson.toJson(object);
return str;
}
}
```

The Users Class:

```
public class Users 
{
   private int id;
   private String username;
   private String password;
   public Users(int id,String username, String password){
     this.id=id;
     this.username = username;
     this.password = password;
   }
   public int getId() {
    return id;
   }
   public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
   }
   public String getUsername(){
    return username;
   }
   public void setUsername(String username){
    this.username = username;
   }
   public String getPassword(){
    return password;
   }
   public void setPassword(String password){
    this.password = password;
   }   
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: please provide a sample response of your backend, so we can better understand what's being done on the client-side.

Comment: Are you sure it's not cross domain problem？Make sure success callback function is called.

Comment: This is the response for the RestURL {"id":1,"username":"harish","password":"ram"}

Comment: success callback is called, And i tried to display the response in alert also. i can get response on alert also. And what is cross domain problem?

Comment: From your REST call, are you passing JSON string to the template?  Or an actual javascript data structure?  Is your `result` variable from the Ajax call a string or a JS data structure?  I'd strongly suggest you do a `console.log(result)` to see EXACTLY what you're getting back from the server and passing to the template.  That will probably show you the issue.  The template expects a javascript data structure, not JSON text.

Comment: I am getting response as JSON String {"id":0,"username":"harish","password":"ram"} and when i print in console log it prints as  Object { id=0, username="harish", password="ram"}

Comment: Then, you will have to show us both the data you are using and a relevant portion of the template you expect it to work with.  Apparently, the two don't match if the data isn't showing up in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by changing at RestURL as follows

```
@GET
@Path("/test1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject getMsg() throws JSONException 
{
    String output ="{ users:  [{username: \"alan\", firstName: \"Alan\", lastName: \"Johnson\", email: \"alan@test.com\" },{username: \"allison\", firstName: \"Allison\", lastName: \"House\", email: \"allison@test.com\" },{username: \"ryan\", firstName: \"Ryan\", lastName: \"Carson\", email: \"ryan@test.com\" }]};";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("id", 3);
    obj.put("userName", 1);
    obj.put("password", 2);
    return obj;        
}
```